# Win32 to set color for Push Button

Tags: winapi, button, colors

As beginner to Win32, I need to create a grid with buttons. So basically for every cell within grid I am creating button as following message:

```
DrawFrameControl(gdc,&rect,DFC_BUTTON,DFCS_BUTTONPUSH|DFCS_FLAT);
```

Now I need to set color to the button. How I can do it.

Comment: Either `HBRUSH hBrush = ::CreateSolidBrush(...)` followed by `::FillRect(&rect, hBrush)` OR `::SetBkColor(...)` followed by `::ExtTextOut(...)`. The second option has better performance but is less understandable.

Comment: Tried it ... HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(102, 255, 192));
FillRect(gdc, &rect, hBrush);
DrawFrameControl(gdc,&rect,DFC_BUTTON,DFCS_BUTTONPUSH|DFCS_FLAT);

not working.

Comment: -1 "Not working" is not good enough. Nobody can help you if you cannot show clearly what you have tried, and explained in detail how it failed to meet your expectations.

Comment: :)
I am using this sample [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/681771/Simple-Grid-A-Win-message-based-grid-control) to create a grid, now in DisplayColumn(...) of BabyGrid.cpp, it's creating Button using DrawFrameControl(gdc,&rect,DFC_BUTTON,DFCS_BUTTONPUSH|DFCS_FLAT); (Changed to Push Button). Now as per above suggestion: I tried ...HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(102, 255, 192)); FillRect(gdc, &rect, hBrush); followed by DrawFrameControl(...). But the color of Button is didn't changed, it's still gray ...

Now what's other options (I am using Win32 only) ...

Comment: While through the other way suggested above, SetBkColor(...) followed by ExtTextOut(...), I need X, Y coordinate for ExtTextOut(...) as per document [Link] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162713%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I need to draw a button in Cells of the grid. As through sub-items of LVITEMA, how i can get X/Y coordinate for every subitems.

Comment: "-2"

what should I say ... very nice ... :)

Comment: The downvotes are because your question is unclear. You started off telling us it is "not working". Then you tried to add information, but you posted it in the *comments*. That's bad because people don't see it there. Plus, you don't get code formatting or anything. Use the [edit] link to put all of this information into your question.

Comment: I note it. :) I will keep your suggestions in mind for further questions. Your suggestions will be helpful for me @Cody Gray.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with `DrawFrameControl`. It always draws with the system colors. They are, of course, configurable by the user in the Personalization control panel, but they are set to a drab gray by default.

Worse, `DrawFrameControl` is an old API that does not take theming (also known as "visual styles") into account. The buttons it draws will look like the classic button controls in Windows 95. You have to use one of the [theming APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773187.aspx) to pick up these styles.

In order to get a custom color, you will need to handle all of the drawing yourself. There is no shortcut.

If you wanted an *actual* button control, you would create a new window with the `BUTTON` window class and the `BS_OWNERDRAW` window style. That would cause the button control to send `WM_DRAWITEM` messages to its parent window, where you would write all of the custom drawing code.

If you just want something that *looks* like a button (which is what it seems like you want here), you don't need to create actual controls. You can just handle the parent window's `WM_PAINT` message and draw the pseudo-buttons. I think this is what you were trying to do already with `DrawFrameControl`. But—as I mentioned—`DrawFrameControl` always draws with its own colors, and is drawing on top of the colored boxes that the well-meaning commenters have suggested that you draw first. What you can do is simulate the effect of `DrawFrameControl` by using the [`DrawEdge` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162477.aspx). That will basically just draw the border of the button, letting you fill in the middle with whatever you want—a color, a pattern, an image, etc. Sample code:

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
   PAINTSTRUCT ps;
   BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);


   RECT rcButton;
   rcButton.left   = 50;
   rcButton.top    = 50;
   rcButton.right  = rcButton.left + 75;
   rcButton.bottom = rcButton.top  + 23;

   // Set the DC's background color to whatever color we want the button to be.
   // In this case, we use a nice orange. You can use anything you want.
   // Or even fill the background with an image.
   COLORREF clrOriginal = SetBkColor(ps.hdc, RGB(255, 128, 0));
   if (clrOriginal != CLR_INVALID)
   {
      // Fill the button's rectangle with a solid color.
      ExtTextOut(ps.hdc, 30, 30, ETO_OPAQUE, &rcButton, NULL, 0, NULL);

      // Draw the button's border.
      DrawEdge(ps.hdc, &rcButton, EDGE_RAISED, BF_TOPLEFT | BF_BOTTOMRIGHT);

      // Restore the DC's original background color.
      SetBkColor(ps.hdc, clrOriginal);
   }


   EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
   break;
}
```

Result:

[image]

It works, but it's not pretty, since it doesn't respect the system theme. You will need the [`DrawThemeEdge` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773298.aspx) for that. And a *lot* more time to invest learning the Visual Styles API.

Comment: Let me try it and I have some study material (DrawThemeEdge) for weekends.

Comment: Thanks a ton, It's a solution.